# Pass variables after timeout sessionstate

Tags: asp.net, session-state

An application I'm working on relies on sessionState for timeout, but there is a need to have custom banners on the login that need to occur after the timeout occurs.  Is there a way to pass values or variables to the login page after a timeout?

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />
```

Comment: OT for mode=InProc, you don't need those connection strings

Comment: Removing those connection strings results in the session not starting.  I'm not sure how you'd eliminate them.